# Error releasing structure pointer using free

Tags: c, pointers, memory, dynamic, allocation

**Hi, technologists. I'm new here. This is my first time to ask questions here. Please forgive me if I have done something wrong. I hope you can be more patient with me. Thank you very much.
I've been studying PointersOnC. And then I had a little trouble writing exercises. The topic is to write a program to achieve matrix multiplication. I defined a structure and named it a matrix. There are variables x and y of type int in the matrix, x and y store the row and column values. The matrix also has a secondary pointer of type int to store the values in the matrix. I define a struct level pointer in the main function and allocate memory through the function. It then allocates the secondary pointer in the structure and stores the value in the secondary pointer. But I had a problem freeing memory. I first release the first level of the second level pointer, then release the second level pointer, and finally release the structure pointer. An error was reported while releasing the structure pointer. **

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
    int x, y;           // Rows and Columns
    int** values;       // Numbers in the matrix
} matrix;
// Initialization matrix
bool InitMatrix(matrix** m)
{
    *m = (matrix*)malloc(sizeof(matrix*));
    if (!*m)
        return false;

    (*m)->x = 0, (*m)->y = 0;
    (*m)->values = NULL;        // Secondary pointer

    return true;
}
// Dynamic memory allocation two-dimensional array
bool mallocTowAry(matrix* m)
{
    if (m->x == 0 || m->y == 0)
        return false;
    m->values = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * m->x);
    if (!m->values)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < m->x; i++)
    {
        m->values[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * m->y);
        if (m->values[i] == NULL)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
// Store the number of the matrix in the array
void assginTow(matrix* m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m->x; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter the elements in the i-th row, separated by spaces:\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < m->y; j++)
            scanf("%d", &m->values[i][j]);
    }
}
// Initialize the secondary pointer in the structure
bool assginMatrix(matrix* m, int x, int y)
{
    m->x = x, m->y = y;
    if (!mallocTowAry(m))
        return false;
    assginTow(m);

    return true;
}
// Print matrix
void showMatrix(matrix* m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m->x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->y; j++)
            printf("%d ", m->values[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    matrix* m_1;
    // Initialize the matrix, but without x and y
    if (!InitMatrix(&m_1))
        return 1;

    int x, y;
    printf("Please enter the row and column values, separated by spaces: \n");
    // Read in x and y
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    if (!assginMatrix(m_1, x, y))
        return 2;
    
    showMatrix(m_1);
    
    // Destroy the matrix
    DestoryMatrix(&m_1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I started editing your question by removing basically all your words that attempt to describe the code, and separating parts of your program out more logically so it's not just a dump.  Then I ran into a curious problem, because your whole question seems based around the call to `DestroyMatrix` yet your code example does not even show that function.  It's possible that the error occurs before then, since you are new to pointers and any mistakes can cause strange issues.  But it's also possible the error is in the one piece of code you didn't show.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answers. Yes, I want to write a program about matrix multiplication. But there was a problem when I wrote the test, so I can't continue. Regarding your answer, I don't know if you have encountered the problem I described, and an error will be reported when the memory is released. Can you send the code here? I'm a newcomer and I don't know much about it.